# magento skin messed up

Tags: magento-1.6

All

Suddenly, magento loading css,js like this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:81/skin/m/1406186283/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/styles.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/widgets.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/account.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/j2t/ajax_cart.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/mypackage-v1.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/global.css,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/css/category.css" media="all" />


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:81/skin/m/1406186314/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js,/js/lib/ccard.js,/js/prototype/validation.js,/js/scriptaculous/builder.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js,/js/scriptaculous/controls.js,/js/scriptaculous/slider.js,/js/varien/js.js,/js/varien/form.js,/js/varien/menu.js,/js/mage/translate.js,/js/mage/cookies.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/j2t/ajax_cart.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jsFn.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jquery.countdown.min.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jquery.hoverIntent.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/tinyFunctions.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jquery.totemticker.min.js,/skin/frontend/mypackage/default/js/jquery.mainbanner.js" ></script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: your stylesheets and js file are merge so magento loading css and js like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have installed the [Fooman Speedster](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-speedster.html) extension. Follow the troubleshooting guide posted [here](http://cdn.fooman.co.nz/media/custom/upload/InstructionsandTroubleshooting-FoomanSpeedster.pdf). In particular make sure that the permissions are correctly set for lib/minify/m.php so that it can be executed.

Comment: thanks very much, I disabled fooman extension and then all js,css loading correctly.